# Remove text between square brackets at the end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex to remove last expression between brackets (also with brackets)

source: input[something][something2]
target: input[something]

I've tried this, but it removes all two:

```
"input[something][something2]".replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `\[.*?\]$` won't work as it will match the *first* `[` (because a regex engine processes the string from left to right), and then will match all the rest of the string up to the `]` at its end. So, it will match `[something][something2]` in `input[something][something2]`.

You may specify the end of string anchor and use `[^\][]*` (matching zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`) instead of `.*?`:

```
\[[^\][]*]$
```

See the JS demo:

```js
console.log(
   "input[something][something2]".replace(/\[[^\][]*]$/, '')
);
```

**Details**:

- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `[^\][]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a literal `]`
- `$` - end of string

Another way is to use `.*` at the start of the pattern to grab the whole line, capture it, and the let it backtrack to get the last `[...]`:

```js
console.log(
   "input[something][something2]".replace(/^(.*)\[.*]$/, '$1')
);
```

Here, `$1` is the backreference to the value captured with `(.*)` subpattern. However, it will work a bit differently, since it will return all up to the last `[` in the string, and then all after that `[` including the bracket will get removed.

Comment: thank you, this code works. I accept it in 10 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the `g` modifier, and use the `$` anchor:

```
"input[something][something2]".replace(/\[[^\]]*\]$/, '');
```

Comment: @ManicDepression Ah, yes. Updated the pattern now.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```js
var str = "Hello, this is Mike (example)";

alert(str.replace(/\s*\(.*?\)\s*/g, ''));
```

Comment: Please make this into a snippet so we can see it working.